# Python Compare two specific dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

I want to compare two specific dictionaries :

```
dict1 = {"person1": {
      "name": "toto",
      "age": 24
    }, 
    "person2": {
      "name": "titi",
      "age": 24}
    }

dict2 = {"person2": {
      "name": "tata",
      "age": 22
    }, 
    "person3": {
      "name": "tete",
      "age": 25}
    }
```

I want to compare the difference between :
- person1,person2 (dict1) and person2, person3 (dict2)
- if the person2 is the same, and to compare name and age if it is the same or not

I already compare the first key, but the second key value not.

The dict1 is the true dictionnary :

```
def not_matches(dict_one, dict_two):
    dict_one = set(dict_one)
    dict_two = set(dict_two)
    ldel, ladd = list(dict_two - dict_one), list(dict_one - dict_two)
    return ldel, ladd

list_delete = list()
list_add = list()

list_delete, list_add = not_matches(dict1, dict2)
print(list_delete)
print(list_add)

['person3']
['person1']
```

Comment: Does the order of the people matter?

Comment: Can you show us your code as well so that we can figure out what's not working? 
Since you've already compared the first key, you are on the right track.

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for defining a dictionary. You need `{}` around the whole dictionary.

Comment: I updated the post :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
for k1, v1 in dict1.items():
  v2 = dict2.get(k1, None)
  if v2:
    print(k1, '---- found:')
    print(v1['name'], v2['name'])
    print(v1['age'], v2['age'])
```

Add customisation for comparing the nested keys.

---

To compare the main keys, the class [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set) comes in hand:

```
keys1 = set(dict1.keys())
keys2 = set(dict2.keys())

print(keys1 - keys2) #=> {'person1'}
print(keys2 - keys1) #=> {'person3'}
print(keys1 & keys2) #=> {'person2'}
```

So the above code could be changed into:

```
for k in keys2 & keys1:
  d1, d2 = dict1[k], dict2[k]
  print ( (d1['name'] == d2['name']) & (d1['age'] == d2['age']))
```

Comment: thanks, it gives me the difference between name and age, but I want also to give me the difference between person name

Comment: If there is intersection between the dictionaries, it compares 'name' and 'age' as required. If you change to print(k1, '---- found:') you get which person is shared between the dictionaries. You can set `keys1 = set(dict1.keys())` and `keys2 = set(dict2.keys())`, then use **set methods** to compare the main key. But it's not clear to me how you want to present the end result.

Comment: I made an edit. I don't know if I get the point. Or maybe you can present the expected result.

Comment: your algo display all key, but I want display only the difference for the first algo

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get the point. Unless you show an example of expected output I can not fix.

Comment: I mean , it s display person3 even though is correct, there is the same age and the same name, so I don't want to display :((
I just want to display, person1 and person2

Comment: I fixed, with that :
if v2 and (v1['name] != v2['name'] or v1['age'] != v2['age']):